# Asterisk Broadcasting

Tags: asterisk

Goodmorning,

I need your help with something. 
A quick question to learn more about Asterisk.

I love studying new things.

I would like to send a broadcasting message too let's say 100+ registered users with Asterisk from one user account.

Would this be possible with Asterisk?

Is there already a function inside 
Asterisk available for this or not?

Thank you.

Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an update on this topic, as Arheops says it is impossible.
It is possible!

I have made it work with the Asterisk AMI.

You call an extension and from the dialplan you kick a PHP script that executes an Asterisk AMI action. This way you can get all the currently active user in a conversation. You can take the currently active users from a real-time database structure. With the dialplan you set autoanswer for these users, this way you can broadcast. Have tested this multiple times, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no function like that in asterisk(it is PBX!!!)

Broadcasting require alot of checks be made and in most case your provider in contract disallow broadcast.

You can use vicidial.org software or write your own using call files(not recommended for person without experience).

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-auto-dial-out/